# Stylesheets not loading on mobile devices

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I got a little bit desperate, since my stylesheets don't want to work on any mobile device (I tried using Android, Chrome for Android, Iphone, Android tablet...)

I know that i had to add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and i also tried importing the stylesheets instead of linking them.

the pattern of the linking looks like the following:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  media="all" />
```

The html is loading fine on all devices, but there is NO css at all on mobile...

Comment: Could you create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: did you tried checking in developer option on mobile?

Comment: @Billy I'll create a fiddle for that later, sorry i forgot that. Nilesh uhm, i might look dumb now but how do i activate developer option on mobile browser? or you mean the general developer mode?

Comment: I will have a look when you uploaded your fiddle @JanSchuermann.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have written css for responsive or in media query there will not have any css. If you can provide the url the problem may solved.

Comment: Looking at his href, he is trying to load bootstrap. I'm pretty damn sure they did the job right in that stylesheet.

Comment: Haven't you used bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

you can check by writing css within media query for mobile width.

```
 @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {

 }
```

Comment: you dont want to load stylesheet on mobile?

Comment: i don't get your question? I tried it and it is not working. not with linked stylesheets, not with imported and not with dedicated @media query